# How to unninstall linux distro in trialboot?

Tags: grub

I have ubuntu, fedora and windows installed in my laptop. I installed ubuntu after windows and then I installed fedora. How can I unninstall fedora without messing up the grub, which was reinstalled during the fedora installation?

Answer (score 0):

After installing fedora the grub is reinstalled on your hdd and managed from fedora :

You need to :

1) Remove Fedora

2) Reinstall grub through the [following steps](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd)

Answer (score 0):

In ubuntu `sudo grub-install /dev/sdX`  For X placeholder your Harddrive. `sudo update-grub`
I'am to slow again.